# Do these axioms define a boolean algebra?

Tags: order-theory, boolean-algebra, lattice-orders

In Awodey's "Category Theory", he defines a boolean algebra $\mathcal{B}$ as

- a poset $(B,\leq)$ along with
- two elements $0$ and $1$, along with
- two binary operations $\lor, \land$, and
- an unary operation $\lnot$

such that

1. $0 \leq a$
2. $a \leq 1$
3. $a \leq c,\;b \leq c \iff a \lor b \leq c$
4. $c \leq a,\;c \leq b \iff c \leq a \land b$
5. $a \leq \lnot b \iff a \land b = 0$
6. $\lnot \lnot a = a$

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_(order)#Complements_and_pseudo-complements) I see that a boolean algebra is a distributive complemented lattice. The first 4 axioms make $\mathcal{B}$ a bounded lattice, and I was able to convince myself that 1-6 imply that the lattice is complemented and that the complement is unique.

I can not seem to show that 1-6 imply distributivity. I can use 3-4 to show that
$$
(a \land b) \lor (a \land c) \leq a \land (b \lor c)
$$
But can't show that 1-6 imply the converse, i.e. that 1-6 imply
$$
a \land (b \lor c) \leq (a \land b) \lor (a \land c)
$$

Comment: How do you even prove $(a \land b) \leq a$ from these axioms?

Comment: @bof you're right, I hadn't seen that those were bi-implications, thanks

Comment: The wikipedia does assert a distorted version of that, namely that a distributive complimented lattice has a unique complement.

Comment: Axioms $1$ and $2$ are dual to each other, as are $3$ and $4$. Axiom $6$ is self-dual. The dual of Axiom $5$ is "$\lnot b \leq a \iff a \lor b=1$".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you already deduced that
$$x\wedge x = x,\quad
x\wedge y = y \wedge x,\quad
x\wedge(y\wedge z) = (x\wedge y)\wedge z$$
are identities satisfied by the algebra.
(And also that $a\wedge b=a$ iff $a\leq b$.)
Now consider the result

> **Theorem** (O. Frink).
> Let $\mathbf A = (A,\cdot,',0)$ be an algebra of type $(2,1,0)$ (that is, $\cdot$ is binary, $'$ is unary, and $0$ is nullary), such that
> $(1)\quad xx=x$,
> $(2)\quad xy=yx,$
> $(3)\quad (xy)z=x(yz),$
> $(4)\quad xy=x$ iff $xy'=0$.
> Define $\mathbf B = (A,\cdot,+,',0,1)$, where $x+y=(x'y')'$ and $1=0'$.
> Then $\mathbf B$ is a Boolean algebra.

The original proof is in
O. Frink, *Representations of Boolean algebras*, Bulletin Amer. Math. Soc. **47** (1941) 775-776.

An alternative proof (without using duality) can be found in
R. Padmanabhan, *A first order proof of a theorem of Frink*, Algebra Universalis, **13** (1981) 397-400.
Here, there is an explicit proof of the distributivity.

Now you only have to prove that your algebra satisfies condition $(4)$ of Frink's theorem.
Using your conditions (5) and (6), if $a$ and $b$ are members of the algebra, then
$$ab=a \Leftrightarrow a \leq b \Leftrightarrow a \leq b'' \Leftrightarrow ab'=0,$$
and so indeed, the algebra satisfies all the hypothesis in the theorem.